# How to convert an object type column with missing values into numeric?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import a CSV file whose column values contain missing values like `(...)` but all other values are numeric. After I use the Pandas command to read my file

```
energy= pd.read_csv('Energy Indicators_v1.csv' ,engine ='python')
```

then the `energy` column gets converted into object type.
Is there a way I can import the column as numeric type, rather than object type.

Comment: What would the missing values convert to?

Comment: example: `df = pd.read_csv("f500.csv", dtype = {"revenues" : "float64"})`

Comment: https://honingds.com/blog/pandas-read_csv/